# Django: Database not making migrations

Tags: django, sqlite

So I royally messed up my project yesterday. Here's a little recap:

I expanded my project from the Django tutorial (mysite, polls, etc.) and I wanted to change the file/directory names from these. So when I did that, it messed up my project and I couldn't run anything. So what I decided to do was to change everything back to "polls", "mysite", "static", "templates", etc. But now, whenever I try to restore my database, it tells me that there are no new migrations but no migrations are being added to the "migrations" folder.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`migrate` will only run migrations if they exist. You create the migrations with `makemigrations` first. 
To check which migrations the database has run with `./manage.py migrate --list`. Information about this is stored in the `django_migrations` table and if you rename your apps back and forth the db might think the migrations are already run.

Answer (score 0):

If the `makemigrations` command does not generate you the migrations.py files, then you must create the package `migrations` inside of each of your applications listed in your `settings.py` file.

After that, the `makemigrations` command will generate your migrations.py files, and the `migrate` command will work for you.